# Not correct string passing from httppost

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to send the insert query from HTTPPOST  to PHP server but string is not passing correct.

I am passing:

`INSERT INTO tm_user_master (COMPANY_CODE, USER_CODE,USER_NAME,USER_PASSWORD,USER_TYPE,STATUS_DATE,EXPIRY_DATE,PASSWORD_CHANGED_DATE,LOCK_USER_IND,Department )VALUES('001','003','Test','test','Admin','2014-06-21','2014-06-21','2014-06-21','N','TEST')`

But the string is passing like:

`'\'001\',\'003\',\'Test\',\'test\',\'Admin\',\'2014-06-21\',\'2014-06-21\',\'2014'`

Please suggest me how to pass the correct insert statement from the HTTPPOST.

Comment: Your sending the SQL *string* to the server using POST, including username, passwords.. dont you thing thats unsafe?

Answer (score 0):

### **Why are you passing the entire query via POST? Bad idea! Especially since you show usernames and passwords!**

But for the issue, disable `magic_quotes_gpc` in `php.ini` or if you can't:

```
$_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);
```

Comment: Actually, In android i made one function which is passing query to php server for DAO. I am taking the field value and passing in the function.
Thanks its working..